# Ajax jQuery picture upload - newbie question whats the best way to handle this?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, cakephp

I have a page with a form on it that the user visits to fill in some info before he signs up for a profile. Underneath the form is a preview of what the profile will look like. I have some javascript so that as the user types into the boxes in the form, the corresponding bit of their profile fills with whatever they're typing. IE they type into the 'title' form input and it will appear in the id="title" div below.

In that form I also have a field so the user can upload a photograph. When the user chooses the pic he wants to upload and closes the dialog, I'd like a resized (so that it fits my max height/width requirements) image to also appear in the preview bit below the form. All this would happen before the profile form had been submitted.

Whats the best way to go about this? I've done a fair bit of googling and while there's plenty of plugings they all seem to either do something far too complicated or miss something out. Can anyone please tell me the best way to handle this?

Thanks :)

If it makes any difference I'm using cakephp.

Side question - is there a way to make sure that when the choose file dialog opens, there is only the option to select image file types. IE all the .doc .xlt etc aren't there?

Comment: @DamienPirsy thanks for the info. The reason I was hoping for a plugin was just because I'm new to javascript never mind jquery and I haven't a baldy how I'd go about doing it all :) Do you know any good tutorials where I could get a rough outline of how to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As to your first question, you'll have to upload the file.  So you'd upload the image and store it in a temporary location that you can still stream back in an IMG element.  When the user saves the form, you can then discard the temp image.  You'll probably also need some sort of cron/scheduled task that cleans them up if folks never save the information and just leave.

As to your second question, nope.  You can check it on the client after they have selected a file, but then I strongly recommend checking it again on the server.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I'm new to javascript so don't really know how to go about doing all that. Do you know of any plugins that do similar? Or is it even javascript you're suggesting to use? I really appreciate your help :)

Comment: I don't know of any plugins that do all of that.  Files can't be uploaded via ajax.  But you could use the jQuery.form plugin to handle the file upload which will basically created a hidden iframe and submit it that way.  Upload it to a specific action in your controller and send a response back to the client, including some data on how to populate the IMG tag with the correct src.  Your response handler for jquery.form plugin will give you the info, then just populate the elements via jQuery().attr() method.